# Can four women be witnesses in cases where two male witnesses are necessary?

Tags: fiqh, men-women, witness

Allah the almighty said:

> ... And bring to witness two witnesses from among your men. And if there are not two men [available], then a man and two women from those whom you accept as witnesses - so that if one of the women errs, then the other can remind her. ... ([2:282](https://legacy.quran.com/2/282))

So we learn that in case we need two male witnesses, we may replace one male witness with two female witnesses.

Are there any scholarly opinions on whether replacing male witnesses by the double amount of female witnesses is allowed?

Or expressed differently: Can four women be witnesses instead of two men, or must there always be at least one male witness for testimony?